# Error Selecting a DATEDIFF within IF Condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In a MySQL query, I am trying to select either a `DATEDIFF()` or `NOW()` based on an `IF()` condition. The behavior of MySQL is confusing me here.

This query run in phpMyAdmin has some strange results. The values should be identical, but they are not.

```
SELECT
                 TIMEDIFF(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), NOW())  AS `A`,
IF(FALSE, NOW(), TIMEDIFF(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), NOW())) AS `B`

A ----------------- | B -----------------
01:00:00 ---------- | 2001-00-00 00:00:00
```

If I try this query, changing `NOW()` to `NULL` in the first option of the `IF` condition, it shows the proper result for the `TIMEDIFF`.  Why is this?

```
SELECT
                TIMEDIFF(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), NOW())  AS `A`,
IF(FALSE, NULL, TIMEDIFF(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), NOW())) AS `B`

A ----------------- | B -----------------
01:00:00 ---------- | 01:00:00
```

So then my question is: how is `NOW()` versus `NULL` affecting the `IF` return?

Comment: What does it return in the first statement?

Comment: I tried the case.  Still the same result when I add in the NOW().

Comment: may be NOW function has to return a value in all cases, because I  was testing the same query with RAND() and SQRT() functions but in that case it is returning the correct value, so may be the issue is with now function return value

Comment: same thing with curdate function

Comment: got an ans... see if it works good with you, worked for me

Answer (score 0):

May be `NOW()` or other date functions have to return a value in all cases, because I was testing the same query with `RAND()` and `SQRT()` functions but in that case it is returning the correct value, so may be the issue is with `NOW()` function return value

TRY using `NOW()` with a blank `CONCAT()`,it won't manipulate your return value also, and it worked well both with `TRUE` and `FALSE`

```
 SELECT
      TIMEDIFF(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), NOW())  AS `A`,
 IF(TRUE, CONCAT(NOW()), TIMEDIFF(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), NOW())) AS `B`
```

OR

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF( DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 HOUR ) , NOW( ) ) AS  `A` , 
CASE WHEN TRUE THEN TIMEDIFF( DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 HOUR ) , NOW( ) ) 
ELSE CONCAT( NOW( ) ) 
END AS  `B
```

both gave correct result

Answer (score 0):

I submitted this is a bug and it was just verified by MySQL staff members.
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71322